# AMAZON SP-API - Access to requested resource is denied - Postman

Tags: postman, amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to get the order list. When I call via postman with below information I get error in reply.

AMAZON_MARKETPLACE=A33AVAJ2PDY3EV

Orders are not coming.

I get the error "Access to the requested resource is denied"
Steps I did:

I have created the IAM user, IAM role, and IAM policies.
I have created the seller account and developer account as well.
I am using the role ARN in my seller central app.

[image]

Comment: Did you sign your request?